# How does this code behave (function composition in funcall)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have the following function in lisp:

```
(defun F(F)
  #'(lambda (n)
      (if (zerop n)
         (funcall F n)
         (1+ (funcall (F F) (1- n))))))
```

How does this code behaves if I call:

```
(funcall (F #'(lambda (x) (+ 2 x))) 2)
```

I dont understand why the output is 4.

Thanks in advance

Comment: nobody knows whats going on in this function?

Comment: Please have some patience. People often take a few hours to respond, especially if the tag isn't [c#] or [java]. ;-)

Comment: Just a question, can I expand the line (1+ (funcall (F F) (1- n))) like this: (1+ (funcall (F (+ 2 x)) (1- n))). Is this like a composition of functions?

Comment: also, i noticed that the argument and the function have the same name does this hava any implication?

Comment: You might want to read up on [multiple namespaces in Common Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328512/why-multiple-namespaces).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we know the argument, we can simplify the `if` statement in the function:

```
(funcall (F #'(lambda (x) (+ 2 x))) 2)
(1+ (funcall (F #'(lambda (x) (+ 2 x))) 1))
(1+ (1+ (funcall #'(lambda (x) (+ 2 x)) 0)))
(1+ (1+ 2))
4
```

The first 2 transformations replace `(if false A B)` with `B`, while the 3rd replaces `(if true A B)` with `A`.

Comment: so, in the line  (1+ (funcall (F F) (1- n)))))), in funcall (F F) he is calling himself again and not the argument. Right?

Comment: @LuisAlves: both :-) it's calling itself on its argument

Comment: Can you explain me how does he knows the first F corresponds to the funtion itself and not to the argument?

Comment: I found out it's because in LISP if in a compound form the first element (the car) is a symbol, then it must be evaluated as a funtion. If the first element it's not a symbol than it must be a lambda expression. Thanks. Also I add this link with a better explanation http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/functions.html

Answer (score 3):

First, untangle the two `F`:

```
(defun foo (fun)
  #'(lambda (n)
      (if (zerop n)
          (funcall fun n)
          (1+ (funcall (foo fun) (1- n))))))
```

Now, you call:

```
(funcall (foo #'(lambda (x) (+ 2 x))) 2)
```

We can give the inner lambda a name, I'll call it `add-2`.

```
(funcall (foo #'add-2) 2)
```

`(Foo #'add-2)` then returns the function

```
(lambda (n)
  (if (zerop n)
      (funcall #'add-2 n) ; n is always 0 here
      (1+ (funcall (foo #'add-2) (1- n)))))
```

This gets called with `2`, which is not `zerop`, so it is:

```
(1+ (funcall (foo #'add-2) 1))
```

We already know what `(foo #'add-2)` returns, and it gets called with `1` now, which still is not `zerop`:

```
(1+ (1+ (funcall (foo #'add-2) 0)))
```

Now the argument is `0`, so we get to the base case:

```
(1+ (1+ (funcall #'add-2 0)))
```

We now can see that `foo` creates a function that adds `n` to the result of calling `(fun 0)`.