# Is defun or setf preferred for creating function definitions in common lisp and why?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

What is the fundamental difference in the functions defined using `defun` and `setf` as below and is one method preferred over another outside of style considerations?

Using `defun`:

```
* (defun myfirst (l)
    (car l) )
MYFIRST

* (myfirst '(A B C))

A
```

Using `setf`:

```
* (setf (fdefinition 'myfirst) #'(lambda (l) (car l)))

#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (L)) {10021B477B}>
* (myfirst '(A B C))

A
```

If, as according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)#Lambda_expressions_and_function_definition):

> named functions are created by storing a lambda expression in a symbol using the defun macro

Using `setf` to create a variable in a different way requires the use of `funcall`:

```
* (defvar myfirst)

MYFIRST
* (setf myfirst (lambda (l) (car l)))

#<Interpreted Function (LAMBDA (X) (+ X X)) {48035001}>
* (funcall myfirst '(A B C))

A
```

My understanding is that this type of variable is different than the previous in that this variable is not found in the same namespace as the defun bound symbol as described in [Why multiple namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3328512/850781).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, one should never underestimate the importance of style.
We write code not just for computers to run, but, much more importantly, for people to read.
Making code readable and understandable for people is a very important aspect of software development.

Second, yes, *there is* a big difference between [`(setf fdefinition)`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_fdefin.htm) and [`defun`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defun.htm).

The "small" differences are that `defun` can also set the [doc string](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_docume.htm) of the function name (actually, depending on how your imeplementation works, it might do that with lambda also), and creates a named [`block`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_block.htm) (seen in the macroexpansions below) which you would otherwise have to create yourself if you want to.

The big difference is that the compiler "knows" about `defun` and will process it appropriately.

E.g., if your file is

```
(defun foo (x)
  (+ (* x x) x 1))
(defun bar (x)
  (+ (foo 1 2 x) x))
```

then the compiler will probably warn you that you call `foo` in `bar` with the wrong number of arguments:

> WARNING: in BAR in lines 3..4 : FOO was called with 3 arguments, but it requires 1
>            argument.
>   [FOO was defined in lines 1..2 ]

If you replace the `defun foo` with `(setf (fdefinition 'foo) (lambda ...))`, the compiler is unlikely to handle it as carefully. Moreover, you will probably get a warning along the lines of

> The following functions were used but not defined:
>    FOO

You might want to examine what `defun` does in your implementation by [macroexpanding](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mexp_.htm) it:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(defun foo (x) "doc" (print x)))
```

CLISP expands it to

```
(LET NIL (SYSTEM::REMOVE-OLD-DEFINITIONS 'FOO)
 (SYSTEM::EVAL-WHEN-COMPILE
  (SYSTEM::C-DEFUN 'FOO (SYSTEM::LAMBDA-LIST-TO-SIGNATURE '(X))))
 (SYSTEM::%PUTD 'FOO
  (FUNCTION FOO
   (LAMBDA (X) "doc" (DECLARE (SYSTEM::IN-DEFUN FOO)) (BLOCK FOO (PRINT X)))))
 (EVAL-WHEN (EVAL)
  (SYSTEM::%PUT 'FOO 'SYSTEM::DEFINITION
   (CONS '(DEFUN FOO (X) "doc" (PRINT X)) (THE-ENVIRONMENT))))
 'FOO)
```

SBCL does:

```
(PROGN
 (EVAL-WHEN (:COMPILE-TOPLEVEL) (SB-C:%COMPILER-DEFUN 'FOO NIL T))
 (SB-IMPL::%DEFUN 'FOO
                  (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA FOO
                      (X)
                    "doc"
                    (BLOCK FOO (PRINT X)))
                  (SB-C:SOURCE-LOCATION)))
```

The point here is that `defun` has a lot "under the hood", and for a reason. `setf fdefinition` is, on the other hand, more of "what you see is what you get", i.e., no magic involved.

This does not mean that `setf fdefinition` has no place in a modern lisp codebase. You can use it, e.g., to implement a "poor man's [`trace`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_tracec.htm)" (UNTESTED):

```
(defun trace (symbol)
  (setf (get symbol 'old-def) (fdefinition symbol)
        (fdefinition symbol)
        (lambda (&rest args) 
          (print (cons symbol args))
          (apply (get symbol 'old-def) args))))
(defun untrace (symbol)
  (setf (fdefinition symbol) (get symbol 'old-def))
  (remprop symbol 'odd-def))
```

Comment: DEFUN will also create a named block. One would have to add that to the lambda.