# How is the defun macro implemented in lisp?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'd like to learn more about lisp macros and I want to create a simple implementation of the `defun` macro.
I'm also interested in lisp's source code in all the implementations.

Comment: Why not check it out yourself and then ask specific questions? There are many open source Lisp implementations you can study. If you want to learn about Lisp macros I would recommend 'On Lisp' - free PDF of that book : http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html

Comment: At first I didn't know where to search.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a tricky question, because of [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)): [`defun`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defun.htm) does a lot of things (iow, calls a lot of functions), but to define those functions one needs a working `defun`. Thus there are three(3!) definitions of `defun` in [clisp/src/init.lisp](https://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/tip/tree/src/init.lisp): at lines

1. [228](https://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/tip/tree/src/init.lisp#228)
2. [1789](https://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/tip/tree/src/init.lisp#1789)
3. [1946](https://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/tip/tree/src/init.lisp#1946)

The very basic definition of defun could be this:

```
(defmacro defun (fname lambda-list &rest body)
  `(setf (fdefinition ',fname)
         (lambda ,lambda-list 
           (block ,fname ,@body))))
```

In fact, this is the first definition of `defun` in CLISP (line 228), except that there is no [`defmacro`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defmac.htm) and no [backquote](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_df.htm) at that moment **yet**, so the actual code looks a lot uglier.

See also [Is defun or setf preferred for creating function definitions in common lisp and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42057102/850781) where I discuss macroexpansions of `defun`s.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily check how your particular CL implementation, implemented `defun` by running

```
(macroexpand '(defun add2 (x) (+ x 2)))
```

On `SBCL` it expands to:

```
(PROGN
  (EVAL-WHEN (:COMPILE-TOPLEVEL) (SB-C:%COMPILER-DEFUN 'ADD2 NIL T))
  (SB-IMPL::%DEFUN 'ADD2
                   (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA ADD2
                       (X)
                     (BLOCK ADD2 (+ X 2)))
                   (SB-C:SOURCE-LOCATION)))
T
```

To see the particular source code that implemented the I would use (on Emacs) the `M-.` key binding and then I will write `defun` and hit enter. Then Emacs will get to the source code:

```
(sb!xc:defmacro defun (&environment env name lambda-list &body body)
  #!+sb-doc
  "Define a function at top level."
[...]
```

I am not going to paste the whole macro as it is rather long. If you are not on Emacs, you can try searching in the repos as most implementations are open source.

BTW `defun` is not so special. You can implement much of it with `setf`-inf a `symbol-function` to a lambda. E.g.:

```
(setf (symbol-function 'ADD3) #'(lambda (x) (+ x 3)))
; => #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X)) {1006E94EBB}>
(add3 4)
; => 7
```