# Dynamically defining setf expanders

Tags: macros, common-lisp, symbols, dynamically-generated, setf

I'm trying to define a macro that'll take a struct's name, a key, and the name of a hash table in the struct and define functions to access and modify the value under the key in the hash.

```
(defmacro make-hash-accessor (struct-name key hash)
  (let ((key-accessor  (gensym))
        (hash-accessor (gensym)))
    `(let ((,key-accessor  (accessor-name ,struct-name ,key))
           (,hash-accessor (accessor-name ,struct-name ,hash)))
       (setf (fdefinition ,key-accessor) ; reads
             (lambda (instance)
               (gethash ',key
                (funcall ,hash-accessor instance))))
       (setf (fdefinition '(setf ,key-accessor)) ; modifies
             (lambda (instance to-value)
               (setf (gethash ',key
                      (funcall ,hash-accessor instance))
                 to-value))))))

;; Returns the symbol that would be the name of an accessor for a struct's slot
(defmacro accessor-name (struct-name slot)
  `(intern
    (concatenate 'string (symbol-name ',struct-name) "-" (symbol-name ',slot))))
```

To test this I have:

```
(defstruct tester
  (hash (make-hash-table)))

(defvar too (make-tester))
(setf (gethash 'x (tester-hash too)) 3)
```

When I run

```
(make-hash-accessor tester x hash)
```

then

```
(tester-x too)
```

it returns `3 T`, as it should, but

```
(setf (tester-x too) 5)
```

gives the error:

```
The function (COMMON-LISP:SETF COMMON-LISP-USER::TESTER-X) is undefined.
   [Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]
```

`(macroexpand-1 '(make-hash-accessor tester x hash))` expands to

```
(LET ((#:G690 (ACCESSOR-NAME TESTER X)) (#:G691 (ACCESSOR-NAME TESTER HASH)))
  (SETF (FDEFINITION #:G690)
        (LAMBDA (INSTANCE) (GETHASH 'X (FUNCALL #:G691 INSTANCE))))
  (SETF (FDEFINITION '(SETF #:G690))
        (LAMBDA (INSTANCE TO-VALUE)
          (SETF (GETHASH 'X (FUNCALL #:G691 INSTANCE)) TO-VALUE))))
T
```

I'm using SBCL. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`defun`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defun.htm) whenever possible.
Specifically, here instead of [`defmacro`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defmac.htm) for `accessor-name` and instead of [`(setf fdefinition)`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_fdefin.htm) for your accessors:

```lisp
(defmacro define-hash-accessor (struct-name key hash)
  (flet ((concat-symbols (s1 s2)
           (intern (concatenate 'string (symbol-name s1) "-" (symbol-name s2)))))
    (let ((hash-key (concat-symbols struct-name key))
          (get-hash (concat-symbols struct-name hash)))
      `(progn
         (defun ,hash-key (instance)
           (gethash ',key (,get-hash instance)))
         (defun (setf ,hash-key) (to-value instance)
           (setf (gethash ',key (,get-hash instance)) to-value))
         ',hash-key))))
(defstruct tester
  (hash (make-hash-table)))
(defvar too (make-tester))
(setf (gethash 'x (tester-hash too)) 3)
too
==> #S(TESTER :HASH #S(HASH-TABLE :TEST FASTHASH-EQL (X . 3)))
(define-hash-accessor tester x hash)
==> tester-x
(tester-x too)
==> 7; T
(setf (tester-x too) 5)
too
==> #S(TESTER :HASH #S(HASH-TABLE :TEST FASTHASH-EQL (X . 5)))
```

Note that I use a more conventional name for the macro: since it *defines* accessorts, it is common to name it `define-...` (cf. [`define-condition`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defi_5.htm), [`defpackage`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpkg.htm)).
`make-...` is usually used for *functions* returning objects (cf. [`make-package`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mk_pkg.htm)).

See also [Is defun or setf preferred for creating function definitions in common lisp and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42057102/850781)
Remember, style is important, both in indentation and in naming variables, functions, and macros.

Comment: It might be clearer to name the macro `DEFINE-HASH-ACCESSOR`, since it's defining functions, not returning them. Maybe also move `ACCESSOR-NAME` to a local function, so one doesn't need to worry about it being available at compile time.

Comment: @jkiiski: you are right, I tried to stay with the OP's notation, but I will edit.